# What does Ctrl-| (pipe key) do in a terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, ipython

For example, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (a. k. a. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>) in a IPython session I get a `Quit (core dumped)` message. Where is this keybinding bound and how can I deactivate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sends SIGQUIT to an application which does produce core dump. It is the same as if you typed `kill -3 PID` where PID is you program process id.

For more info, read  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: Is there any way to change the keybindings to the signal in a Linux system?

Comment: Not as far as I know. These are hard-coded at the system level

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what "system level" means, since it's vague.

This is the old-fashioned terminal (tty) interface. You can control how key sequences are processed, at the terminal-driver level. See stty. For instance,

> stty quit ''

should disable the default translation of ctrl-pipe into a QUIT.

Ultimately, doing this at the shell command-line may not help you, since some interactive apps impose their own stty settings, thus overriding/undoing what you already set at the command-line.